# Webpage viewer in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython, html

Does wxPython support viewing pages that embed css, javascript and flash content in any way? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup, see wxWebKit (implements Apple's WebKit for wx)

http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/index.php